# modify katex output html/css?

Tags: mathjax, katex

I've been pretty impressed with Katex's performance. It seems like a good fit as a rendering engine for a WYSIWIG latex editor. However, with MathJax, I can easily inject HTML/CSS in arbitrary locations using the `\class` directive. I can then use these injected classes for blinking cursors, gray boxes, and what not. For example:

[image: WYSIWIG editor]

Is there a way to do the same thing with Katex? In particular, I need the ability to inject HTML/CSS in arbitrary locations in the equation.

Comment: If you want a KaTeX-based WISYWIG, you may want to check out Guppy: https://github.com/daniel3735928559/guppy

Comment: Also, MathQuill may be of interest to you, but it has somewhat limited capabilities: http://mathquill.com/

Answer (score 3):

This is not currently supported. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/issues/90) on the Github page.

Comment: Now current `KaTeX` is supported `WYSIWYG` LaTeX editor? Please confirm.